# Stop people from embedding my website in their Android App/iOS App/Website?

Tags: android, ios, web

I searched thoroughly for this and found info on preventing an `iFrame`, but not an Android or iOS app.

Basically, some blockhead decided to embed my website into his/her Android app and "enhance" it. I assume it's `<webview>`? (not experienced with Android yet)

Thought about claiming via copyright, but shutting it down via code would be better.

How do I stop them from doing this on an Android app? Is it with JS I can block it or block requests from the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hosting a public website there is no way you can do this.

You could try and do user agent detection but that's just a hack that can easily be changed on the app developers part and will also hurt users who are simply using Android phones from accessing your website.

It would be best to reach out to the developer. You should also realize that client side manipulation of CSS, etc. is not forbidden so really it would just come down to if he is claiming something to be his own in the copyright sense.

Comment: I reached out but the person isn't responding. I guess I could just let it go as you said, they can't really manipulate anything.

Comment: Correct and a server/website should be setup properly so any API endpoints, etc. perform their own validation.